# Setting innerText with Javascript only applies momentarily

Tags: javascript, html

So I am learning Javascript, and I'm having a problem:

I can set the innerText of a paragraph element. But immediately the web-browser undo's my work!! Meaning the web-page completely reverts back to the state it was in as if I had loaded the page afresh.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" onclick="GetCurrentLocation()" value="Get Current URL" />
        </form>
        <p id="CurrentURL">Current URL:</p>

        <script>
            function GetCurrentLocation()
            {
                var myCurrentLocation = window.location.href;
                var curLocP = document.getElementById("CurrentURL");
                curLocP.innerText = "Current URL: " + myCurrentLocation;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So above I set the innertext in the last line of the function, and in the UI I can see the correct, expected text:

**Current URL: C:\Users...\Projects\test.html**

flash and then disappear simply leaving me with:

**Current URL:**

I'm running this on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser submits the form and refreshes the page. That's why you loose changes. Change your input type from `submit` to `button`

```
<input type="button" onclick="GetCurrentLocation()" value="Get Current URL" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked great! This will probably be the one I will use.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return:false` to your JavaScript to prevent the form from being submitted and reloading the page (and making it look like the change disappears when in reality it's just reloading):

```
<input type="submit" onclick="GetCurrentLocation();return false" value="Get Current URL" />
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t2kkE/)**

Answer (score 1):

The browser submits the form that's why the refresh happens.
If you need to use a submit button you can use `event.preventDefault()`

```
function GetCurrentLocation(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var myCurrentLocation = window.location.href;
    var curLocP = document.getElementById("CurrentURL");
    curLocP.innerText = "Current URL: " + myCurrentLocation;
}
```